# squid3 configuration file to allow all requests including https

Tags: proxy, https, squid

What is the simplest squid3 configuration file to implement a proxy on port 8888 that allows all requests from all clients to all sites including https?

Comment: Your clients will be using port 8888 for HTTPS?

Comment: sure why not...?